# Complex limits regarding the logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I am relatively new to complex analysis, and in my course we have to calculate the following limits (if they exist):

$\lim \limits_{z \to 1}\frac{log(z)}{z}~~~~~$
$\lim \limits_{z \to -1}\frac{log(z)}{z}~~~~~$
$\lim \limits_{z \to 0} z \cdot log(z)$

The first one should be clear, since log is defined at $1$ and is continuous in the domain $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$. So I can simply evaluate $\lim \limits_{z \to 1}\frac{log(z)}{z} = \frac{log(1)}{1} = 0$
right ?
I am not sure about the second and third. I know that L'Hospitals rule works in the complex numbers as well, so i am supposed to get $\lim \limits_{z \to -1}\frac{log(z)}{z} = -1$  and
$\lim \limits_{z \to 0} z \cdot log(z) = 0$. At least if I am not forgetting about some precondition of L'Hospital. But this is not what I am supposed to do, since I haven't even gotten introduced to complex derivations yet. Is there a simple way yo evaluate these limits if I only have elementary definitions of complex analysis?

Comment: Which definition of logarithm are you working with?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken z=x+iy in complex analysis and your working out the limit as x tends to one, not z tends to one

Comment: the inverse of the exponentioal function if you restrict it to $\mathbb{R} \times (-\pi , \pi). So $log$ is only defined on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$.

Comment: @ricky oh no, I just got it wrong. There is not supposed to be a $x$ anywhere

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I also know $log(z)=log(|z|)+i \cdot arg(z)$

Comment: Your second limit should be $-i\pi$

Comment: @ricky how did you get that? I can't use L'Hospital after all

Comment: i posted it in the answer column

Comment: Why would you need l'Hospital when the limit has a finite numerator and denominator?

Comment: @PeterForeman I don't think this is a requirement for L'Hospital right? But if the function is not defined at -1, then what else can I do

Comment: L'Hopitals rule MUST have an infinite numerator and denominator OR both numerator and denominator which tend to $0$.

Comment: @PeterForeman not in the definition I gave above, and I think otherwise $log$ would not even be a continuous function, so you couldn't even swap the limit and the logarithm

Answer (score 0):

$\lim \limits_{z \to -1}\frac{log(z)}{z}~~~~~$ for this limit, I would use the fact since $i^2=-1$ and by log rules change $\frac{log(-1)}{-1}$ to $\frac{log(i)}{-1}+\frac{log(i)}{-1}$

As @joséCarlosSantos stated $log(z)=log(||)+iarg(z)$ this leads to $log(i)=\frac{i}{2}\pi$ thus:

$\lim \limits_{z \to -1}\frac{log(z)}{z}$=$\frac{log(-1)}{-1}$ =$\frac{log(i)}{-1}+\frac{log(i)}{-1}$=$\frac{-i}{2}\pi$$\frac{i}{-2}\pi$=$-i\pi$

Comment: We did not define the complex logarith on the negative real numbers though, so I can't just drag the limit into the logarithm. After all $log$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm here read this

Comment: I am not sure what on wikipedia you are referring to, it at least is not helping me figure out where I am wrong. I don't see why you can swap limit and logarithm, and i don't see why your 'logarithm rules' apply. If you consider only one branch of the logarith then sure.. But since you write $log(-1)$ you are clearly assuming it's domain to be the whole punctured plane